# How do I access a new Vagrant box's files?

Tags: vagrant, vagrant-windows

I'm new to using Vagrant as a dev environment. Previously, I could browse files via going to 'My Computer' and accessing a drive like I would access C: drive.

Yesterday my dev box was upgraded, but now I no longer have access to this drive and so cannot browse the files on Vagrant anymore.

Would anyone know how to get this back or how I can browse files again (other than through command line)?

(ps, this is on Windows 7).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to map it to Windows by:

- My Computer >> Map network drive button at top of window
- Choose unoccupied drive
- In folder field enter IP of new vagrant box, eg:
  \111.111.000.111\desiredfolder
- Click finish